# Is there a scaffolding for elementary OS app unit testing?

Tags: testing

I'm trying to learn to make applications with vala, and i'm fond of test driven developpement. But i can't find any example of real tested code in vala, envelope has one Unit Test, but i don't manage to adapt it in other projects.

here's my tests directory's Cmake file :

```
pkg_check_modules(DEPS REQUIRED
  granite>=0.3
  gtksourceview-3.0>=3.10
  gthread-2.0
  gtk+-3.0>=3.9.10
)

set (PKG_DEPS
 granite>=0.3
 gee-0.8
 gtksourceview-3.0
 gtk+-3.0
 webkit2gtk-4.0
 discount
)

set (VALA_DEPS
 granite
 gee-0.8
 gtksourceview-3.0
 gtk+-3.0
 webkit2gtk-4.0
 discount
)


find_package(Vala REQUIRED)

include(ValaVersion)
ensure_vala_version("0.23.2" MINIMUM)

include(ValaPrecompile)
enable_testing ()

add_definitions(${DEPS_CFLAGS})
add_definitions ("-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=\"${GETTEXT_PACKAGE}\"")
add_definitions (${CC_OPTS})

link_libraries(${DEPS_LIBRARIES})
link_directories(${DEPS_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set (LIBS ${LIBS} enotes-clib)
set (EXEC_NAME_TESTS "enotes-tests")

vala_precompile(VALA_C_TEST ${EXEC_NAME_TESTS}
  ../src/Main.vala
  ../src/Application.vala
  ../src/Widgets/Editor.vala
  ../src/Widgets/Headerbar.vala
  ../src/Widgets/ViewEditStack.vala
  ../src/Widgets/NewNotebookDialog.vala
  ../src/Widgets/PreferencesDialog.vala
  ../src/Widgets/NotebookItem.vala
  ../src/Widgets/BookmarkItem.vala
  ../src/Widgets/TrashItem.vala
  ../src/Widgets/BookmarkButton.vala
  ../src/Widgets/PageItem.vala
  ../src/Widgets/PagesList.vala
  ../src/Widgets/Sidebar.vala
  ../src/Widgets/SidebarItem.vala
  ../src/Widgets/Viewer.vala
  ../src/Widgets/Window.vala
  ../src/Styles/air.vala
  ../src/Styles/elementary.vala
  ../src/Styles/modest.vala
  ../src/Services/Bookmark.vala
  ../src/Services/FileManager.vala
  ../src/Services/Notebook.vala
  ../src/Services/Page.vala
  ../src/Services/Settings.vala
  ../src/Services/Trash.vala
  ../src/config.vala

  FileManagerTest.vala
PACKAGES
  ${VALA_DEPS}
OPTIONS
  ${GLOBAL_VALAC_OPTIONS}
 -g
  --vapidir=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vapi
  --thread
  --target-glib=2.38 # FIXME check before, and target the same version
)


add_executable(${EXEC_NAME_TESTS} ${VALA_C_TEST})
add_test (${EXEC_NAME_TESTS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/enotes-tests)

# copy test data
file(COPY data DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

I obtain an error on add_executable() function :

```
tests/CMakeFiles/enotes-tests.dir/build.make:912: avertissement : surchargement de la recette pour la cible « tests/enotes-tests »
tests/CMakeFiles/enotes-tests.dir/build.make:89: avertissement : ancienne recette ignorée pour la cible « tests/enotes-tests »
make[2]: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « ../tests/enotes-tests », nécessaire pour « tests/enotes-tests ». Arrêt.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:265 : la recette pour la cible « tests/CMakeFiles/enotes-tests.dir/all » a échouée
make[1]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/enotes-tests.dir/all] Erreur 2
Makefile:127 : la recette pour la cible « all » a échouée
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

Besides, envelope is an unmaintained code, i'm wondering how elementary envisions unit testing nowadays. Some people have taken the topic, but unfortunately, i'm a vala beginner, i can't follow their steps :

http://chrisdaley.biz/test-driven-development-in-vala-pt-6.html#test-driven-development-in-vala-pt-6

***EDIT : i'm not talking about writing a CmakeList file for my application, but writing a CmakeList file for tests/ directory. One of the tricky part is dealing with two main() functions.***

If you have any lead on how to write cmake file for unit testing in vala the right way, i'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I should suggest to you to take a look at the elementary OS webpage,  at Developer Section:

[Getting Started](https://elementary.io/en/docs/code/getting-started#)

You can find there how to get cmake modules to elementary-os development and how to write CMakeList files.

Comment: thanks, i've already made this tutorial, but nothing there talks about unit testing, and Cmake for the tests/ directory.